# Primefaces pick list target is always empty

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, picklist

I have a pick list component and I have 2 lists, the first has data from my database and the second is a DualListModel and I have a button to transfer between the pick lists, when I transfer data nothing happenes the source in the DualListModel stays empty.

Here is my JSF code:

```
<p:pickList id="a" value="#{mbInstructor.model}" var="pickQ"
    itemLabel="#{pickQ}" itemValue="#{pickQ}">
     <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{mbInstructor.fullList}" />
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{mbInstructor.onTransfer}" update="msg" />
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mbInstructor.onSelect}" update="msg" />
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{mbInstructor.onUnselect}" update="msg" />
    <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{mbInstructor.onReorder}" update="msg" />
</p:pickList>
```

And here is my methods in the managed bean:

```
private List<Question> fullList;
private DualListModel<Question> model;

public List<SemesterExamQuestionForm> getAllQuestionForms() {
    GeneralFacade facade = new GeneralFacade();
    return facade.lstSemesterExamQuestionForm(getCurrentStudySemesterExam());
}

public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object item : event.getItems()) {
        ((Question) item).getQuestionTxt();
    }
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    msg.setSummary("Items Transferred");
    msg.setDetail(builder.toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

 public List<Question> getFullList() {
        return fullList;
    }

    public DualListModel<Question> getModel() {
        if(model == null){
            model = new DualListModel<>();
        }
        fullList = getAllCourseQuestions();
         model = new DualListModel<>(new ArrayList<>(fullList),new ArrayList<Question>());
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(DualListModel<Question> model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see you should do what you now do in getModel() in a PostConstruct-method or similar. getModel() should only return existing model

Comment: Sorry mate that did not work, I tried to place all the business in the getter method in another method and added the @PostConstruct but got nothing in source or target lists, in the above code I used to get the source list but could not move data to the target.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar
Yes I have a form in the parent and I am updating it, I removed the that logic from the getter and placed it in another method that got load when the page loads, now I am getting the data in the list but when I transfer it nothing happen, I bet I am not doing the transfer anywhere in my code, sorry for that silly question but I am a beginner in java and jsf, can you advice how to transfer the data from the source to the target list when I hit the transfer button?

Comment: Do you have a proper toString-method as advised in Omnifaces? And equals/hashcode

Comment: @jaqenH'ghar I use the debugger and get empty list in the target while my source is filled with the data. I tried the p:growl it adds a message saying transfer successful but the list still empty

Comment: I have the toString and will add the equals method now and let you know

Comment: SessionScoped session

Comment: no problem i did it and now testing my app

Comment: still no luck I have been stuck on this all day long

Comment: Thanks mate for help I solved the issue the issue was occurring only when I refresh the page the target get lost I just noticed that and it was always occurring as I am updating my form on transfer method. but can you advice how to keep the data stored even if i refreshed the page